# Getting java.lang.InterruptedException when running ios builds on a mac mini via jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild

I have a build setup where I check out ios code on a mac mini and run xcodebuild to compile and then push the ipa up to hockey app.

This all happens automatically from a jenkins server which runs on a google cloud linux vm.

Recently i've been running into issues where i get an error in the jenkins job while the xcode build command is running:
"Cannot contact MacMini: java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException"

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

Comment: Is there any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never really got to the bottom of this. Tried upgrading the mac minis and upgrading the network. Looks like there was a timeout with the connection between jenkins and the mac mini due to the long time it took for the code to compile on the mac minis.

Answer (score 0):

TroubleShooting Steps:

1. Check Java installed including JDK and JRE.
2. face same issue slave macine not connect and throw java exception after installing JDK, I found workaround Go to your Salve machine setting and Set

Hope so this will work if you are using ssh connection.

> Host Key Verification Strategy value `Non Verifying verification strategy`